# Thermal throttling on i7-1185G7

Tags: cpu, intel, cpu-frequency, sysfs, sensors

I have a brand new i7-1185G7 laptop whose CPU is being heavily throttled on Linux 5.8.0, even though it's thermals are in bounds (albeit a bit high).

```bsh
$ sensors
ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +48.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.87 V  
curr1:         2.23 A  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +33.0°C  

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +38.9°C  (low  = -60.1°C, high = +89.8°C)
                       (crit = +94.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +54.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
```

Looking at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/thermal_throttle/*` (and via the GNOME CPUFreq extension) I can see that the CPU is being throttled heavily, all of the time and it's noticeable in performance.

I've tried disabling `thermald`, and [this project](https://github.com/erpalma/throttled). No luck.

How can I find out who is throttling me and why? Temperature readings are well below critical.

Comment: Is there a diffrence if you are using battary or AC?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: `performance powersave` (for each cpu) and `scaling_governor` is set to `powersave` for all.

Comment: Yes. Even disabling `intel_pstate` completely does not mitigate the throttling. I am also affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1838141).

Comment: (scaling_cur_freq will go to 4100000 on my i7-1165G7 with scaling_governor set to performance, 1101412 without)

Answer (score 2):

I also have problem with my brand new DELL latitude 5420 (2021) with the same CPU (i7-1185G7) and Linux.

I temporary resolve the issue by running the commands below after system boot:

```
sudo rmmod intel_rapl_msr 
sudo rmmod processor_thermal_device 
sudo rmmod processor_thermal_rapl 
sudo rmmod intel_rapl_common 
sudo rmmod intel_powerclamp

sudo modprobe intel_powerclamp
sudo modprobe intel_rapl_common 
sudo modprobe processor_thermal_rapl 
sudo modprobe processor_thermal_device
sudo modprobe intel_rapl_msr
```

Comment: Have a look at my Dell experience: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582470

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the `intel_pstate` driver improves the situation. The CPU still gets throttled unnecessarily (at low temperatures), but much less so.

To do this, edit `/etc/default/grub`, and add `intel_pstate=disable` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, e.g:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

After saving, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

After much pain, I have finally solved this. Had the same problem.

- First you need to disable `intel_rapl_common` and `intel_rapl_msr` with the `rmmod` command. You also have to disable `thermald`, `tlp`, and `pstate`.
- Then you need to install a dual boot windows and there you have to install the intel dynamic tuning driver. This driver talks to the BIOS somehow, I am not sure how, but I have made tests and the results don't give space for doubts. Without that, I could only get to a score of 4300 multi core in `geekbench`.

After installing the driver on windows and rebooting, I got a refreshing 5600 points on linux! And that is because for the very first time my CPU would reach high temperatures on average 80°C, with some boosts of even 100°C.

If it doesn't work, try installing `dtfp` on your distro. There is a `copr` package for fedora, as an example. It is not an official driver, but I believe Intel is working on its completion.

**Update** I have applied new thermal paste to the processor and integrated GPU, and now it runs so smooth, hardly overheats; I recommend it. The stock thermal paste is too thin, and I think it is intended to last many years. Well, I think it is preferable to change the thermal paste every couple of years so you get a little thermal boost.

Also, regarding Geekbench 5, now it's getting 6000 points! I'd say the top 1% after seeing a lot of results from other computers.

Answer (score 0):

There have been multiple big changes in recent kernel versions in regard to supporting Intel Tiger Lake CPUs. The best course of action would be to run kernel 5.10.x or later.

Answer (score 0):

For the Latitude 7320 it has been solved!

See https://github.com/intel/thermal_daemon/issues/341 for details.